# Add setShouldAppendNewLine to FileWritingMessageHandler in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el

I'm using Spring Integration 4.1.0.

I have a use case where I'd like to produce a single file that will contain a row for each message that flowed to a channel.

Shown below is the config to do that, as per the "Define an integration flow" section of this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/

```
<feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="news" url="https://spring.io/blog.atom">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:transformer
            input-channel="news"
            expression="payload.title + ' @ ' + payload.link + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'"
            output-channel="file"/>

    <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="file"
            mode="APPEND"
            charset="UTF-8"
            directory="/tmp/si"
            filename-generator-expression="'SpringBlog'"/>
```

This seems like a fairly common use-case (at least in my team it certainly is).  You'll note that the `CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler` (for writing to `stdout` and `stderr`) offers the this setter `setShouldAppendNewLine(boolean shouldAppendNewLine)`.  Could a similar setting be offered on the `FileWritingMessageHandler`?

A point could be made to say that is really the job of a transformer (as is shown in the example), however if it's being offered already as a setting on the `CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler` class then a decision was made to combine this special transformer use-case on that class and I see this as a reasonable request to make `FileWritingMessageHandler` behave similarly.  Also with SpEL expressions not necessarily running as fast as compiled code (unless we use the new `spring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED` setting) this would save on some processing time as the transformer step would not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable request to me (given the existing precedent on the stream adapters), especially when writing in `APPEND` mode.

Please open a 'new feature' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Even better, consider [contributing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)!

We generally don't make schema changes mid-stream in point releases (e.g. 4.1.1) so the XML namespace support would have to be deferred until 4.2.

However, adding the property to the class would enable it to be set when using Java `@Configuration`, or by getting a reference to the handler and setting it during application initialization.

Comment: I'll open a JIRA for this and will attempt to contribute the change (might take a few days).

Comment: I've finally added a JIRA for this.  Please see https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3620.  The Pull Request is here:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1361

Comment: Please see JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3621 for the XML namespace support.